# Show output of postinstall script in Apple's installer window

Tags: macos, install

I use a lengthy postinstall script for an installer package. The postinstall script produces lots of log output which is written to `/var/log/installer.log`.

Is there any chance to show this output underneath or above the progress bar in the installer window, since the progress bar seems to "get stuck" for quite a long time with about 95% finished while the postinstall script is running.

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: would publishing your script help us answering your question?

Comment: I don't think so - it's a shell script that writes to stdout with echo commands. This output is written to the installer.log by the Apple installer. Question is, whether or how I can display this log in the installer window.

Comment: Press `cmd`+`L` in installer and you will see this logs.